# Kohana Route setup for different actions

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

I have route like this (Kohana 3.3)

```
Route::set('project', 'project(/<action>(/<id>(/<idfile>)))')
```

now is possible querys like this

```
localhost/kohana/project/edit/16
localhost/kohana/project/list/
```

I want to use pagination on action list - so i need to change "id" to "page" in my route only on this action

Do I should use Regulars or theres a stock approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by next Route

```
Route::set('project', 'project(/<action>(/page/<page>)(/<id>(/<idfile>)))')
```